# Вынимать — я что сделаю?

Tags: глаголы

Существует ли в принципе такая форма глагола?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В русском языке существует два глагола с похожим значением: [вы́нуть](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C) и [вынима́ть](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C).

Вынуть — глагол совершенного вида, подразумевает завершенный процесс извлечения чего-либо наружу (извлечь). Имеет форму будущего времени при склонении по родам, но не имеет формы в настоящем времени (я что сделаю? — ***я вы́ну***).

[Вынима́ть](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/151506) — глагол несовершенного вида (переходный, невозвратный, I спряжение), подразумевает сам процесс перемещения чего-либо изнутри наружу (извлекать). **Этот глагол не имеет формы будущего времени**, употребить его можно только в виде ***буду вынимать*** (я что буду делать?); *будешь вынимать, будет вынимать, будем вынимать...*
Неправильно: выниму, вынему.

*Во вторник я беру с собой на телевидение Машу, компромат будет лежать у нее в сумке, я **буду вынимать** оттуда кассеты... по одной, и перед каждой выемкой Маша получит поцелуй в щечку* (А. Гельман. Профессионалы победы).
*Будешь выкликать по фамилиям, а я **буду вынимать** подарки* (В. П. Катаев. Квадратура круга).

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, существует.

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/вынимать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

*вынимать*

1. Доставать что-либо откуда-либо, извлекать наружу; вытаскивать.

2. Извлекать что-либо вставленное, воткнутое, погруженное куда-либо.

*Вынимать* - несовершенная форма. Обозначает многоразовость или процесс действия.

*Вынуть* - совершенная форма. Обозначает результат действия.